# Why is the Fisher information matrix so important, and why do we need to calculate it?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, fisher-information

I am currently taking a module in predictive analytics and I have come across the Fisher Information Matrix.

Can somebody explain why this is so important, its use and why we need to calculate it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fisher Information matrix is extremely important.  It tells how much information one (input) parameter carries about another (output) value.  So if you had a complete model of human physiology, you could use the Fisher information to tell how knowledge about 1) eating habits, 2) exercise habits, 3) sleep time, and 4) lipstick color affected a person's body mass.  You'd find that the entries corresponding to the first three variables would be large but that the last would be zero.

Comment: So Fischer matrix has nothing to do with our estimated parameter $\theta$, right? We calculate only for the true parameter $\theta^*$? Like the theta we calculate should have generated the data $X$.

Answer (score 0):

Another perspective, the Fisher information matrix is very important because from its inverse we can estimate the variance and covariance of the parameter estimators of a likelihood function.
 $Var\left(\hat{\beta_j}\right)=I^{-1}\left(\hat{\beta}_j\right)$